Triggering USB-C DisplayPort alt-mode with libusbgx
Is it possible to make a linux host behave like a USB-C DisplayPort sink? That is, if I were to plug my device running this code into another computer with a USB-C/USB-C cable, the other computer would see my device as a monitor and send data to it as if it were a monitor.
I believe what I'm describing is a USB gadget for which I know about libusbgx however I don't see anything about the alt-modes in that driver.
At a high level, I am trying to build a virtual monitor where I can plug a device into another computer and my device can process the frames that the computer sends to it as if it were a real, physical monitor.
I know that this requires specific hardware, let's assume I have a device that has that chip on it so it can correctly emulate a USB device.
Note: I explicitly do not want to use UVC here because I don't want to install anything on the other computer and the other computer, sans that code, will not negotiate a UVC sink.
